# How does the import files mechanisem work in Apache ANT

Tags: ant

I'm working on building a large scale project, as part of the build I defined a path in some xml and overridden it in another xml that imports it (or imports a file that imports it).
I noticed that the order of the imports and the location of the overridden path tag in the importing files changes the behavior of the build.
But, I couldn't find the logic behind it.
How does the import work exactly?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The value of ant property cannot be changed once set. If you import a file and the file sets some properties, any other declaration of a property after the import with the same name as a property in the imported file will be ignored.

Suppose you have an external file, file1.xml, which declares a property, foo.

file1.xml: `<property name="foo" value="bar"/>`

Then, in the main file, where you declare the property foo matters in relation to where you import file1.xml.

Suppose you do:

`<import file="file1.xml"/>`

`<property name="foo" value="baz"/>`

Then property `foo` will have a value of `bar`.
On the other hand, if you do:

`<property name="foo" value="baz"/>`

`<import file="file1.xml"/>`

Then property `foo` will have the value `baz`.

The moral of the story is to define any properties whose value you wish to override before you import a file that also declares those properties.

See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html for the ant property task documentation.

Comment: My question was on the importing mechanism of ant and not on the property tag. does anybody know how the import works exactly?